# Android - Gallery strange behaviour with TextView

Tags: android, textview, gallery, flip

I'm using gallery widget with two textView below.

I've added a onItemSelectedListener to change dinamically textView value:

```
    mGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            TextView titleView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleView);
            TextView descriptionView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);
            titleView.setText(title[position]);
            descriptionView.setText(description[position]);           
    }
```

But when I flip on the gallery, there is a problem. The animation isn't fluid, if I remove the "setText" statement, works correctly. I've this problem only on Android 4.0.

There is a way to solve it?

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener, gets called all the time. Are you sure is this the only way to achieve your target?

Comment: I don't know other solutions, how can I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue some time back.. In my opinion its a bug in The Gallery.. I solved it in a kind of hack´ish way by posting the update 400 ms delayed(the duration for snapback). And set setCallbackDuringFling to false so it won´t fire before it´s stopping.

```
mGallery.setCallbackDuringFling (false);

mGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) {

   mGallery.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
                TextView titleView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleView);
                TextView descriptionView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.descriptionView);
                titleView.setText(title[position]);
                descriptionView.setText(description[position]);   
        }
    }, 400);

}
```